# Change datetime if duplicate found in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is a complicated one: I have a dataframe which has column of python datetimes. However some of the datetimes can be duplicates even though other values in the row are different. The reason is that the recording of data only has a granularity of 1 millisecond eg:

```
                          DateTimes     VWPfgbl
26541610 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553000  152.271875
26541611 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553000  152.271875
26541612 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553000  152.271875
26541613 2014-12-04 20:59:08.369000  152.272308
26541614 2014-12-04 20:59:09.321000  152.270476
26541615 2014-12-04 20:59:09.550000  152.261818
26541616 2014-12-04 20:59:09.550000  152.265714
26541617 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.268000
26541618 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.265714
26541619 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.240000
26541620 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.253333
26541621 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.251875
26541622 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.241538
26541623 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.245625
26541624 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.245714
26541625 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.233571
```

What I want to is add 1 microsecond to the next duplicate in the column if it and so on to create something like this:

```
                          DateTimes     VWPfgbl
26541610 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553000  152.271875
26541611 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553001  152.271875
26541612 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553002  152.271875
26541613 2014-12-04 20:59:08.369000  152.272308
26541614 2014-12-04 20:59:09.321000  152.270476
26541615 2014-12-04 20:59:09.550000  152.261818
26541616 2014-12-04 20:59:09.550001  152.265714
26541617 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.268000
26541618 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552001  152.265714
26541619 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552002  152.240000
26541620 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552003  152.253333
26541621 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552004  152.251875
26541622 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552005  152.241538
26541623 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552006  152.245625
26541624 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552007  152.245714
26541625 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552008  152.233571
```

Not really sure how to go about this, maybe for loop through keeping a list of datetimes it has seen before then if duplicate amend to new value and amend the value of the dict key by one.

```
dict = {}
for x in range(0, df.shape[0]-1)
    if df.DateTimes[x] in dict:
        df.DateTimes[x] = df.DateTimes[x] + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=df.DateTimes[x])
        dict[df.DateTimes[x]] = dict[df.DateTimes[x]] + 1
    else:
        df.DateTimes[x] = 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `groupby-cumcount` to number the items in each group. 
Then convert those numbers into NumPy timedelta64's with microsecond resolution. This NumPy array can then be added to `df['DateTimes']` to create the desired values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}')
df['DateTimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTimes'])

microseconds = df.groupby(['DateTimes']).cumcount()
df['DateTimes'] += np.array(microseconds, dtype='m8[us]')

print(df)
```

yields

```
                          DateTimes     VWPfgbl
26541610 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553000  152.271875
26541611 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553001  152.271875
26541612 2014-12-04 20:59:04.553002  152.271875
26541613 2014-12-04 20:59:08.369000  152.272308
26541614 2014-12-04 20:59:09.321000  152.270476
26541615 2014-12-04 20:59:09.550000  152.261818
26541616 2014-12-04 20:59:09.550001  152.265714
26541617 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552000  152.268000
26541618 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552001  152.265714
26541619 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552002  152.240000
26541620 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552003  152.253333
26541621 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552004  152.251875
26541622 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552005  152.241538
26541623 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552006  152.245625
26541624 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552007  152.245714
26541625 2014-12-04 20:59:09.552008  152.233571
```

Comment: Thats a great answer, i never you could do that. Thanks alot